# Vectorizing splitting string values in a column based on strings in another column in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, string, vectorization

Hey so I have this problem of splitting strings in a column based on another column's values, I managed to figure out a solution with df.apply but I wonder if there are any str.split related ways to vectorize this implementation?

```
            name field
0            b_b     b
1            b_c     b
2            b_d     b
3        a_paris     a
4  a_tokyo_ghoul     a
5           a_xx     a
```

I would like to convert the 'name' column into

```
0              b
1              c
2              d
3          paris
4    tokyo_ghoul
5             xx
```

and my current implementation is

```py
df.apply(lambda row: row['name'].split(f"{row['field']}_")[-1], axis=1)
```

Comment: what should happen if, say, the field in row 0 was `c`?

Comment: The field 'name' is generated so that this would not happen

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to extract the field after the first `_` **and validate that the initial string is the same as `df['field']`**:

```
df2 = df['name'].str.split('_', n=1, expand=True)

df['name2'] = df2[1].where(df2[0].eq(df['field']))
```

output:

```
            name field        name2
0            b_b     b            b
1            b_c     b            c
2            b_d     b            d
3        a_paris     a        paris
4  a_tokyo_ghoul     a  tokyo_ghoul
5           a_xx     a           xx
```

Comment: Thanks for the super quick answer! I haven't even finished eating my dinner yet damn! but what about the case when values in the field are strings such as 'more_than_a_letter'? I was looking for a way to not have to hard code which '_' to look for?

Comment: Then you cannot vectorize it, unfortunately

Comment: thank you @mozway, I'm gonna give up thinking on this one haha

Answer (score 0):

If all the name contains '*' in your name column, then you can split the column on basis of '*', this way you got prefix and postfix of data of the name column.
After call the postfix data that come-after '_', this way you get desired output.

Edit*:-  You can also use other columns as a base that contains the prefix data of name field and put filtter that for field str match name column then split rest part